# Is it possible to add a new tag to all current registrations efficiently?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I currently have 160k active registered devices on my notification hub. Each one has a set of tags. I have added a new feature in my application and the user can turn notification on/off for this feature. We currently manage the on/off state by registering a tag. We would like to deploy this feature with everyone on by default, which means we would need to add this tag to every registration. Is it possible to do this efficiently? My current solution is taking way too long:

```
var result = await HubClient.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(currentToken, 100);
foreach(var r in result)
{
  //get installationId from tags
  var id = ...;
  var installation = await HubClient.GetInstallationAsync(id);
  installation.Tags.Add("newtag");
  await HubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
}
```

This is taking way too long and even resulting in `QuotaExceededExceptions`. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Is it possible to avoid the `GetInstallationAsync` call? Possibly getting all `Installations` directly, instead of going through the `Registrations`? How about updating the tags through the `Registration` without going through the `Installation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "no".

Does your app register its push token each time the user starts a session? If so maybe the best approach is to add the tag when each user launches the new version of the app for the first time.

Do you also have a server that keeps track of all the push registrations and user preferences? You could also update your table of all the user preferences with the new default setting, if the new feature does not depend on the user having the latest build of the mobile app.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to do so via batch